# How to copy Drupal website to localhost from Server

Tags: drupal-6

I have to update, add and fix a drupal website.
The website is on a live working server and i have full access to everything.

Drupal version is: `Drupal 6.22`, 2011-05-25

I want to make a copy on my machine (**win7+iis+(any php needed))** to be able to change and test my updates without touching the server.

I already copied the project folder and i found the database file.

The Database is **odb** file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the backup of your project files folder and databse from c panel or from the server folders and SQL command prompt

Then install wamp or xampp in your local system place project folder in c:/wamp/www folder and create a database in **phpMyAdmin** and import database with db backup file.

Then run your project as `localhost/YouProjectFolder` in browser
config the default.ini the site folder and you all set

Answer (score 1):

Download whole database. You can use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) or [Backup_migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate). Then [setup](http://drupal.org/node/350271) a fresh drupal system and inject the whole database there.

As I fortunately never used Windows, unfortunately I can't give you OS specific details. But xampp or similar solutions are there.

Comment: how do i connect the odb to the website?

Comment: When you do a fresh install, it asks database details there. Do what you have to do for odb there, then dump everything once installation is finished.